# Logging In for android app

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app that requires the user to log in after starting the main activity. So I store the status in the Application and update it in the Login Activity.

```
public class AppActivity extends Application {
    ........
    public static boolean isLogged =false;
    ......
}
```

In the main, I check the status, if the user is logged in I show the main activity if not I show the login activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(!AppActivity.isLogged){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Also I check `onResume` if the user is logged in

From there I update the Login Activity like so

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    btnLogin.setOnlickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AppActivity.isLogged = true;
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is,I have to log in twice for the app to redirect me to the main activity

Comment: Do not save state in `static` variable . Use a persistent storage probably `SharedPreference` . Read and write Session state accordingly .

Comment: @ADM, what if the user doesn't shut down the app correctly, the login will be saved and will be logged in automatically next time. isn't writing session data too much especially when it's just used once? Maybe you can also explain why it would update a persistent data but not an in-memory data

Comment: Its totally depends upon your session you want to ask for login to user each time he/she opens the app Then You can use a runtime Global state Which can be done by `Application` class . Or if this is not the case then go with `SharePreference` . So make a choice .

Answer (score 1):

`finish()` is not sending you back to the activity via `onCreate()`, it's simply returning you to the activity. It will, however, send you through that activity's `onResume()`. If you place your login check in onResume instead of onCreate, it will work. There are also other methods you could look at, but that would be the simplest for you to implement with the existing code.

Comment: `onCreate()` is for checking whether the user is logged in on the first start. I also placed the login check in the `onResume()`. Problem is you have to login twice to be redirected. The first time it will show you the login window again

Comment: Based on the questions you're asking, and your response to my answer, I don't think Stack Overflow is the best place to answer your questions. You should do some more research on how to implement a login system use Android lifecycles, and use SO for specific, solvable problems, and not for broad "how to" questions.